# Excel - Search list in 2 lists

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have 2 lists, each on its own sheet.

My goal is to search each cell of the 2nd sheet on each cell of the first sheet, and delete the whole row of the first sheet if its been found.

The cell's content aren't necessarily the same, it can only be a string.

For example, one of the cells in sheet 2 is 'string', but if one of the cells in the first sheet is 'substring', it should delete the whole row of the first sheet.

How should I approach it via VBA?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()
    Dim lastRowSheet1 As Long, lastRowSheet2 As Long, rng As Range, r As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    lastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row    ' total row sheet 2
    lastRowSheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row  ' total row sheet 1

    For j = 1 To lastRowSheet2        'loop thru every cell of sheet 2
        For i = 1 To lastRowSheet1    ' loop thru every cell of sheet 1
            If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: it works, but inefficiently, by forcing 1:1 comparisons when that much work is not necessary :)

Comment: Yes, that is true. It took a while to parse through the +25k rows, but it did it. I will also give your solution a try (: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a "one shot" operation, do a "VLOOKUP" and use the filters to remove found strings.

In VBA, do it with something like :

```
for i = 1 to 65535
    for j = 1 to 65535 
        if sheets("sheet1").range("A" & i).value = sheets("sheet2").range("A" & j).value then
              sheets("sheet1").range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        end if
    next j
next i
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of a partial match. You'd have to re-write your formula using `Instr()` function, e.g., `If Instr(1, sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value, sheets("sheet2).Range("A" & j).Value, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then ...`, minimally, to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

For each cell in the column in Sheet2, look for a partial match in column in sheet 1. Delete the entire row if there is a match, then repeat until no match found.

This assumes your lists are organized in 1 column on each sheet.

```
Sub InCellDeDupe()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim foundRow As Range

Dim r As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim str As String

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1") '<-- modify as needed
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet 2") '<-- modify as needed

Set rng1 = sh1.UsedRange.Columns(1) '<-- modify as needed
Set rng2 = sh2.UsedRange.Columns(1) '<-- modify as needed

For Each cl In rng2
    str = cl.Value

    Do
        Set foundRow = rng1.Find(What:=str, After:=rng1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not foundRow Is Nothing Then
                foundRow.EntireRow.Delete
            Else:
                Exit Do
            End If
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 that'd work. Just one note when using End(xlDown) be careful as if that range contains empty cells you will not get all the data. Better approach of finding last row of column is to use 
Cells(rows.count, column).End(xlUp).row

Comment: yep, my `xlDown` is admittedly sloppy.  Updaed with an even better method :)

Answer (score 1):

The method mansuetus proposed would be very slow as it will have to iterate all 65k rows 65k times and it will not find any substrings.

To improve performance you should dynamically look up the data's lenght and save that.
As for the question of looking up substrings you could use something like that:

```
  If FullCellString = LookupStr Then
        'Match found - delete row
    Else
        If InStr(1, FullCellString, LookupStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            'Match found in substring delete row
        End If
    End If
```